# QueryDsl - How to create Q classes with maven?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I have web project spring mvc with spring data 
here is example :
https://github.com/prilia/SpringJpa-Quarydsl-Test/tree/master/JpaSpringQuarydsl

I checked a lot of pom.xml that I found in web to create a Q classes of entities, but no lack.
Please help me with creating Q classes with maven.

Comment: Have you checked http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/1.1.0/reference/html/ch02.html?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need plugin, try this:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>process-common-model</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <sourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/{yourSourceDir}</sourceDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/querydsl</outputDirectory>
                        <processors>
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </processors>
                        <options>
                            <querydsl.entityAccessors>true</querydsl.entityAccessors>
                            <querydsl.createDefaultVariable>true</querydsl.createDefaultVariable>
                            <querydsl.packageSuffix>.qdsl</querydsl.packageSuffix>
                        </options>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

I copied this from my project. just added it to your `pom` and have a try.

There are additional options in the code above, if you just wanna a simple one, focus on the  [querydsl reference](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02.html)

Comment: after generating the Q-files and using them in project if  by mistake those files got deleted then will it compile again( as mvn clean install will also fail.)

Comment: Adding the plugins alone won't do anything, you need to run `mvn clean install`

Answer (score 0):

The `apt-maven-plugin` from the accepted answer is not maintained for years. It was a source of problems for me when migrating to Spring Boot 3.

You can generate QClasses using the `maven-compiler-plugin`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
                <classifier>jpa</classifier>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </path>
            <!-- In case your project uses Lombok add here the Lombok dep below 
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.30</version>
            </path>-->
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In case you are using Jakarta EE (Spring Boot 3) you need slightly modify the deps:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
                <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            </path>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- In case your project uses Lombok add here the Lombok dep below 
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.30</version>
            </path>-->
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```