# how to write predicate for QueryDslPredicateExecutor

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, predicate, querydsl

When i try to use Querydsl as shown in Spring reference [Spring 1.10.4.RELEASE reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.4.RELEASE/reference/html/) - i get some errors from IDE:
Cannot resolve method findAll(predicate). I changed import to com.mysema.query.types.Predicate. Now method looks fine.
But i cant resolve problem with:

```
Predicate predicate = user.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(username).and((user.getId().equals(userid)).not);
```

I got errors: cannot resolve method: and, cannot resolve method not.

Some from reference:
Example 32. Querydsl integration on repositories

```
interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<User> {

}
```

The above enables to write typesafe queries using Querydsl Predicate s.

```
Predicate predicate = user.firstname.equalsIgnoreCase("dave")
.and(user.lastname.startsWithIgnoreCase("mathews"));

userRepository.findAll(predicate);
```

But example is incorrect.
Anybody know how to use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using the wrong `user` object to start with. I assume you are currently using your domain class `User` but you need to use the class generated by Querydsl, normally named `QUser`.

See https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/tree/master/querydsl-jpa for example code.

See [QueryDsl - How to create Q classes with maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889990/querydsl-how-to-create-q-classes-with-maven) for how to generate the necessary classes with Querydsl.