# QuerydslAnnotationProcessor is not generating Q classes. Spring Querydsl date filtering

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jpa, querydsl

I am implementing entity filters with Querydsl with web support in my spring boot rest api. I want to be able to filter Date fields not by exact match, but by date from or date to. I came across this project

```
https://bitbucket.org/gt_tech/spring-data-querydsl-value-operators/src/master/
```

and it seems to have functionality that I need, but I am having problems with generating Q classes. Currently I am using JPAAnnotationProcessor as a processor, but according to that project documentation I need to use QuerydslAnnotationProcessor. If i replace JPAAnnotationProcessor with QuerydslAnnotationProcessor and perform mvn clean install it does not generate those classes. I also tried using @QueryEntity annotation on Tournament class.

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.tournament</groupId>
<artifactId>tournament</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>tournament</name>
<description>App</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <jvmArguments>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/generated_sources/</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My entity that I want to filter:

```
@Entity
public class Tournament {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    private Date eventStart;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Currently I am able to filter entities by name match, but I need to implement date filtering before or after 2019-09-01 00:00:01 and etc.

How can I fix Q class generation or is there any easier way of achieving this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889990/querydsl-how-to-create-q-classes-with-maven Refer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I needed two plugins instead of one.

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1.4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/querydsl/java
                        </outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.QuerydslAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        <options>
                            <querydsl.logInfo>true</querydsl.logInfo>
                            <querydsl.listAccessors>false</querydsl.listAccessors>
                            <querydsl.useGetters>true</querydsl.useGetters>
                            <querydsl.unknownAsEmbeddable>true</querydsl.unknownAsEmbeddable>
                        </options>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/querydsl/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-test-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.basedir}}/src/test/groovy</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

After adding these plugins everything works fine.