# Issue with QueryDSL on Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, querydsl

I set up my project exactly as depicted on http://zetcode.com/springboot/querydsl/. The QCity class is automatically generated.

Here's the method of the @SpringBootApplication annotated class:

```
@Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        QCity qCity = QCity.city;

        JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);

        query.from(qCity).where(qCity.name.eq("Bratislava")).distinct();
        var c1 = query.fetch();

        logger.info("{}", c1);

}
```

I performed the maven clean and then install

However I got this error log while trying to execute :

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    QCity cannot be resolved to a type
    QCity cannot be resolved to a variable
    var cannot be resolved to a type

    at grupo.artefatoX2.ArtefatoX2Application.run(ArtefatoX2Application.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
```

which points precisely to this line QCity qCity = QCity.city;

The log was shortened.

What went wrong ??

Comment: Path to class QCity is not fine, probably it points to target folder?

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate sources :

```
mvn generate-sources
```

Or include the plugin mentioned here: [QueryDsl - How to create Q classes with maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889990/querydsl-how-to-create-q-classes-with-maven) in your pom as below and run mvn clean install.

Comment: Actually as I wrote QCity class is generated.